# Regex syntax in a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

Hi I have been dissecting my friends code and I am really confused about how the regular expression he used works. I'd really like to understand what each component of his expression is doing.

I console.log the function and see the output, but I want to know HOW the regex gathers the outcome.

Here is the part of the function that has the regex in it:

```
location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
```

Really I'd just like to know the role of each character in the regex : `(/^\//, '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick explanation of the [expression](http://regex101.com/r/lN3lA5):

```
/      # Starting delimiter (so Javascript knows this is a regular expression)
 ^     # Match the start of the string
 \/    # Match a / (needs to be escaped with \)
/      # Ending delimiter
```

As for the [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function, it takes the string (`location.pathname`) and replaces the first parameter (either a string or regular expression) with the second parameter (either a string or a callback function returning a string).  This means the backslash at the very beginning of `location.pathname` will be replaced with a blank string.

Comment: Sweet, that helps a lot thanks Sam. I think the escaped **/** was confusing me

Comment: No problem, there are many [special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) in regex. If we hadn't escaped the `/`, Javascript would've thought we had hit the closing delimiter (`/^/`).

Answer (score 0):

The regex needs to be defined between `/` characters, `^` means "begins with" and `/` needs to be escaped, hence the `\` in front of it. So that is removing the first `/` in `pathname`